# How can I find specific word in URL and change or delete it?

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace, preg-match

Like this URL;

```
/?action=proc&pr_id=5
```

I want to find "pr_id" and change it as "pr" => /?action=proc&pr=5;

But if URL is like;

```
/?action=proc&pr_id=5&pr=5
```

I want to find "pr_id" again and delete it => /?action=proc&pr=5

I get URL

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and want to change it with preg_match but How can I write regex for this?

Comment: Do you want to redirect? Or edit the string for other reasons? Would apache mod_rewrite be an option? (URL manipulation in the webserver)

Comment: Why would you want to use regex? You can achieve this with simple search and replace.

Comment: If you're getting this from `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, then I think these parameters are also available from `$_GET`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use $_GET to achieve what you want.

```
$get_values = $_GET;

if (isset($get_values['pr_id'])) {
    if (!isset($get_values['pr']) {
        $get_values['pr'] = $get_values['pr_id'];
    } 
    unset($get_values['pr_id']);
}
```

Then reconstruct the URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from one URL to another you can use Apache mod_rewrite module.

Go to your Apache config file `httpd.conf`, make sure that the module is loaded

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then in your virtual host or .htaccess (if it's on) add the next lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?action=([a-z]+)&pr_id=([0-9]+)$ /?action$1&pr=$2 [L]
```

If you want to have the access to variables passing in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, use $_GET variable.

```
<?
print_r($_GET); // prints the array of all variables coming in GET request
print $_GET['action']; // prints your action variable
print $_GET['pr_id']; // prints your pr_id variable
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only regex, only hardcore!

```
$url = preg_replace('%(&|\?)pr=.?(&|$)%', '$1', $url);
$url = preg_replace('%(&|\?)pr_id=%', '$1pr=', $url);
$url = trim($url, '&');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

you are using str_replace() function to replace a string like:

```
$url = str_replace('pr_id','pr',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $url;
```